# Amasty: "shopby" redirect on custom product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, extensions

I'm working on a small module which I usually test on my local magento installation. Everything worked so I uploaded the files to our magento test environment, which is online and has already a few other modules installed. One of those is "Amasty Shopby".

My module is supposed to show a custom product collection in catalog view based on `$_GET` values.
An example URL could look like this:

```
http://example.com/mymodule/index/get/?5=2
```

So far everything works, I get a collection of products based on `$_GET['5'] == 2` (In my case those are Attributes). But if I switch from Grid to List mode (or other way around) or change the sort direction I get redirected to following URL:

```
http://example.com/shopby?mode=list&5=2
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/mymodule/index/get/?mode=list&5=2
```

If I hit the back button (from browser) now I get redirected back to

```
http://example.com/mymodule/index/get/?5=2
```

but the mode switches from grid to list (or other way around).

Everything works fine with pagination, switching pages works.
What's weird is that it also doesn't work when disabling Amasty through backend though it should be worth to mention that the toolbar isn't shown at all when disabling "Amasty Shopby". On my local magento installation (without Amasty or any other modules) everthing works as expected. If more information is required please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need both grid and list?

Comment: Not necessarily but I'd like to give our customers the flexibility to choose the mode. I also expect this weird behavior when changing sort order of products though I cant confirm it yet. I really would like to know why this happens since everything works fine on a clean installation.

Comment: I see. Thought you developed only for your own project.